# Simulating failure of calloc by setting char pointer to NULL

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

**** This question is very confused, because I missed something in my program, but the answers to this question are insightful (for me anyway). If you are having a similar problem, I would suggest that you focus on the answers rather than on my code ****

I am trying to write a program that can handle failure of memory allocation by informing the user of the failure, but working around it. (I understand that this is not the right thing to do in most situations).

I have a structure. One of its structure variables is:

```
char* name;
```

At some point, I have the following line, allocating memory for this variable dynamically and setting it to some input:

```
if(object->name = calloc(1, strlen(input)+1)){
    strcpy(object->name, input);
}
```

I want to check behavior of the program in the case that calloc fails to allocate memory. I wrote a test where I replaced the above line of code with:

```
object->name = NULL; //instead of the calloc
```

Because I reckon that calloc will return NULL if it fails to allocate memory.

However, I get a segmentation fault on that line when I do it. I think it is because I have not allocated memory for object->name. However, that is precisely my point. I just want to set the pointer to the char array to be NULL. I want to check for this NULL pointer somewhere later in the program and work around it.

How would I make object->name a NULL pointer without getting the segmentation fault?

---

because I have not included enough detail above, this is the actual code:

```
 //disk is the "object" in question
if(disk_ptr = calloc (1, sizeof (disk))){
        disk_created_successfully = set_or_fix_disk_static_attributes_test_all_is_null(&disk_ptr, name);
        ...
}
```

Where

```
bool set_or_fix_disk_static_attributes_test_all_is_null(disk** disk_ptr, char* name){
    int success = true;
    (*disk_ptr)->name = NULL;
    // Code fails here
    ...
    return success;
}
```

Comment: I read the last sentence of your question, re-read it, still I'm clueless. :-( What is the difference you're expecting, actually?

Comment: Sorry, will edit in a moment. I see what you mean.

Comment: or, maybe, we're missing a simple thing here, that while doing `object->name = NULL;`, `object` itself is NULL or invalid?

Comment: I think it's best if you show *where* you're setting the NULL value. I suspect you do that inside the `if` thus writing to unallocated memory in `strcpy` or making some other similar "mess"

Comment: @Amit in this particular case, `if (<NULL>)` will prevent the `strcpy()`, but we don't know the full code.

Comment: Ah, I am sorry. I should have included the full code.  I was trying to make the post more readable. I now included where I am setting the NULL and the place where I create the object (disk) itself.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I meant inside the `if` in the sense of after the condition is evaluated.. in the "truthy" block

Comment: ...and how do you use `(*disk_ptr)->name` later?

Comment: Do you want to know about the code in the question, or about your code?

Comment: Note about `calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size)`:  With `calloc(1, strlen(input)+1)`, the result should only be `NULL` when out-of-memory as both `nmemb > 0` and `size > 0`.  Should one of them have the value of 0, `calloc()` could return `NULL` _or_ not-`NULL` even with sufficient memory resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see from your snippet, if `object` is allocated peroper memory,

```
 object->name = NULL;
```

is fine and legal. However, in that case, at any later point, any code similar to

```
 strcpy(object->name, input);
```

will be illegal, as you'll be essentially trying to write into invalid memory. in general, any subsequent access to read from and write to `object->name` should be blocked.

---

EDIT:

I think you're a bit confused. As your post says, if you're trying to simulate the `calloc()` failure, then you must be be setting the `disk_ptr` to NULL. Then, inside the `set_or_fix_disk_static_attributes_test_all_is_null()` function, the instruction

```
(*disk_ptr)->name = NULL;
```

is becoming invalid, as you'll be de-referencing the NULL pointer. You may want to add a check for the `*disk_ptr` against NULL first.

Comment: Yep - I was using object->name without a check for NULL later in the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To test the condition, you could change

```
if(object->name = calloc(1, strlen(input)+1)){
    strcpy(object->name, input);
}
```

to

```
if (0) {
    strcpy(object->name, input);
}
```

That is, your original code is checking that the allocation succeeds.  The result of it failing is that "false" is the condition.

Probably there is other code which uses `object->name`, so a more comprehensive test is:

```
if (object->name = NULL) {
    strcpy(object->name, input);
}
```

Comment: On a side note, not to confuse `=` with `==`. We are not comparing `object->name` to `NULL`, in fact we are not implicitly comparing anything. The behaviour in that case is that this `if ()` statement will pass for anything that is not zero. Taken that a `NULL` pointer is arithmetically equivalent to 0, the `if ()` statement won't pass if `object->name` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test for a NULL pointer immediately after the call to `calloc`.  If you reference that NULL pointer at any point you're asking for trouble.

In this case, that would be right after the point where you manually set your pointer to NULL.